# Admob does not show test ads nor real ads

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, admob

I've been struggling with Admob ads for almost a week now and I searched all over the internet to find a possible solution but nothing worked. My Android application does not show test ads nor live ads. This is the log:

```
I/Ads: Updating ad debug logging enablement.
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
    SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v13280019.11910000.1
I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
W/Ads: App does not have the required permissions to get location
    I/Ads: Trying mediation network: 
    I/Ads: Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.DummyAdapter
    I/Ads: No fill from any mediation ad networks.
    I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
    W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
```

My test interstitial loads with no problem, the live one doesn't. The banner does not show, not the test one nor the live one.

This is my xml AdView:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"> //test admob unit id
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

And I load the banner with:

```
     MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.app_id));
 adView1 = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("my_test_device_id").build();
adView1.loadAd(adRequest1);
```

The live interstitial is loaded in this way, and it works (the test one does not):

```
final InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
          mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("_live_ad_id");
          mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("my_test_device_id").build());
          mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
              @Override
              public void onAdLoaded(){
                  mInterstitialAd.show();

              }
          });
          if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
          } else {
              Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
          }
```

**Things I've tried**

- compile gradle with `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'`
- compile gradle with firebase ads, following the guide in the firebase site and connecting firebase to my admob account
- include the AdView inside a Relative and Linear Layout
- change the ad size
- change activity and layout

Nothing worked. From what I've understood my log say the ad request is successful but admob does not have ads to display at the moment. Maybe the live ads are not shown because my app is not live yet but why the test ads does not show? And why only the live interstitial ad work? I also thought my admob account could be disabled but the ads works on my other applications.

Comment: This happens with one of my ad spaces as well. No live ads and no test ads, no fill. I believe it's because we've requested the ad too many times from a certain device/ip/something combination. The ads fill fine for users.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the problem. I've tried with two other devices and the banner loads correctly. However is very frustating because the ads doesn't show in the device I use for testing and I not always have available other physical devices to try the app.

Answer (score 3):

change your `ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"` to `ads:adUnitId="your_banner_id"`

**Note:** `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111` its for testing !

try this code for banner

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.app_id));
 adView1 = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("my_test_device_id").build();
adView1.loadAd(adRequest1);
```

For InterstitialAd

```
MobileAds.initialize(LoginActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.app_id));

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

         mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.full_screen_ads_id));
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .build());
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                    super.onAdLoaded();

                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi,thank you but the problem is still here. The interstitial works correctly but there is no way to make the banner work. However why the test ads cannot be shown?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Please post if you manage to resolve this

Comment: @rickyxd do you replace this with your ads id ?`ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" `

Comment: @kdblue Yes, now I'm using my live ads unit IDs created in the admob site. However there is no way to show the banners (test and live) and the test interstitial in my phone (OnePlus 5) but I managed to try the app in another device and both the test and live ads works correctly. At the moment I can't understand why this happen and it's very frustrating because I don't always have other physical devices, if not my OnePlus 5.

Comment: @grebulon try to test your application in another device and post if it will work

Comment: @rickyxd okay , can you tried code without `addTestDevice("my_test_device_id")` ? , comment it and try !

Comment: @rickyxd, I have tried on several devices, with addTestDevice, using test unit - several combinations, and many other things. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This might be old but perhaps it helps someone.

You could be receiving this error for many reasons.

Two other reasons are:

1. If you are using test ads and everything is setup correctly, Google might be blocking your app id (com.example.myapp) for some reasons if you previously were on production (Billing, address, etc...), it won't even work on test IDs; try changing your app id and check if it works.
2. If you are using production IDs, your account may not be active yet; You simply have to wait until it becomes active.