# Why Admob ads not showing up on actual devices?

Tags: android, admob, whatsapp

**First of all, some days ago some ads worked, but today i noticed they stopped working, i dont know if i changed something.**

***They dont work in any device, and im not using test ads***

In the test device of Android studio they show up with the little text on the top that says "test ad" (im using my admob ids so its not a problem) but then when i make the APK and run it on a device ads dont show up, at all, not even a test one, they are just gone, let me show you what i mean:

**In the test virtual device:** https://gyazo.com/704e18c00544794ec4e29faad1a1ab8d

**In an actual device:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t8vx.jpg

I will put here some code, but i dont know what code should i put here so i let you guys tell me what to send so you guys can see whats the problem.

**All the files that have something to do with the ads are this ones in the gif:**
https://gyazo.com/8ca6c2b10e9b392c424f641ffaefb26a

*(Tell me what files do you want me to send and i will send it here)*

**(Sorry for bad english, im from spain)**

***I censored the ad ids and app ids with ///////!***

List Activity

```
package com.example.samplestickerapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;


public class StickerPackListActivity extends AddStickerPackActivity {
    private PublisherAdView mPublisherAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_LIST_DATA = "sticker_pack_list";
    private static final int STICKER_PREVIEW_DISPLAY_LIMIT = 5;
    private LinearLayoutManager packLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerView packRecyclerView;
    private StickerPackListAdapter allStickerPacksListAdapter;
    private WhiteListCheckAsyncTask whiteListCheckAsyncTask;
    private ArrayList<StickerPack> stickerPackList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sticker_pack_list);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-///////////~/////////");
        mPublisherAdView = findViewById(R.id.publisherAdView);
        PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        mPublisherAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        packRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.sticker_pack_list);
        stickerPackList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_LIST_DATA);
        showStickerPackList(stickerPackList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        whiteListCheckAsyncTask = new WhiteListCheckAsyncTask(this);
        whiteListCheckAsyncTask.execute(stickerPackList.toArray(new StickerPack[stickerPackList.size()]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (whiteListCheckAsyncTask != null && !whiteListCheckAsyncTask.isCancelled()) {
            whiteListCheckAsyncTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    private void showStickerPackList(List<StickerPack> stickerPackList) {
        allStickerPacksListAdapter = new StickerPackListAdapter(stickerPackList, onAddButtonClickedListener);
        packRecyclerView.setAdapter(allStickerPacksListAdapter);
        packLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        packLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(
                packRecyclerView.getContext(),
                packLayoutManager.getOrientation()
        );
        packRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        packRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(packLayoutManager);
        packRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this::recalculateColumnCount);
    }


    private final StickerPackListAdapter.OnAddButtonClickedListener onAddButtonClickedListener = pack -> {
        addStickerPackToWhatsApp(pack.identifier, pack.name);
    };

    private void recalculateColumnCount() {
        final int previewSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sticker_pack_list_item_preview_image_size);
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = packLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        StickerPackListItemViewHolder viewHolder = (StickerPackListItemViewHolder) packRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(firstVisibleItemPosition);
        if (viewHolder != null) {
            final int max = Math.max(viewHolder.imageRowView.getMeasuredWidth() / previewSize, 1);
            int numColumns = Math.min(STICKER_PREVIEW_DISPLAY_LIMIT, max);
            allStickerPacksListAdapter.setMaxNumberOfStickersInARow(numColumns);
        }
    }


    static class WhiteListCheckAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<StickerPack, Void, List<StickerPack>> {
        private final WeakReference<StickerPackListActivity> stickerPackListActivityWeakReference;

        WhiteListCheckAsyncTask(StickerPackListActivity stickerPackListActivity) {
            this.stickerPackListActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(stickerPackListActivity);
        }

        @Override
        protected final List<StickerPack> doInBackground(StickerPack... stickerPackArray) {
            final StickerPackListActivity stickerPackListActivity = stickerPackListActivityWeakReference.get();
            if (stickerPackListActivity == null) {
                return Arrays.asList(stickerPackArray);
            }
            for (StickerPack stickerPack : stickerPackArray) {
                stickerPack.setIsWhitelisted(WhitelistCheck.isWhitelisted(stickerPackListActivity, stickerPack.identifier));
            }
            return Arrays.asList(stickerPackArray);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<StickerPack> stickerPackList) {
            final StickerPackListActivity stickerPackListActivity = stickerPackListActivityWeakReference.get();
            if (stickerPackListActivity != null) {
                stickerPackListActivity.allStickerPacksListAdapter.setStickerPackList(stickerPackList);
                stickerPackListActivity.allStickerPacksListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.samplestickerapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".StickerApplication"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".EntryActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StickerPackListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sticker_packs_list" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StickerPackDetailsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StickerPackListActivity"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.samplestickerapp.StickerPackListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StickerPackInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sticker_pack_info"
            android:parentActivityName=".StickerPackDetailsActivity"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.samplestickerapp.StickerPackDetailsActivity" />
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name=".StickerContentProvider"
            android:authorities="${contentProviderAuthority}"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:readPermission="com.whatsapp.sticker.READ" />
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
                    android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app-pub-/////////////~//////////"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-/////////////~//////////"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Admob does not show test ads nor real ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336373/admob-does-not-show-test-ads-nor-real-ads)

Comment: Did you connect your app on playstore with google ad account?

Comment: i dont have the app on play store, right now i cant pay the 25$, and admob doesent let me change payment methods until i have the minimal ammount of money.

Answer (score 0):

After you create your admob account and add your app, you get your application id that you use in manifest and for initializing ads.

Now you need to create **add units** for your add from your adMob account and link your add unit id with the addView that you are displaying in your device.

If you have used default code from website, you might be using id for test ad-unit. You need to replace that with your **ad unit id**.

Once you have published your app, you need to connect your app on Google play with your adMob account.

And lastly, the adds will only show up when internet connection is available.

**Edit based on Comment**

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
     android:value = "your-application-id-goes-here"/>
```

> ```
> Make sure you have updated AdMob with your payment details
> Make sure that the ads you created in AdMob are banner ads.
> Check your AdMob dashboard to see the status of your ads, are they active?
> Verify you used the correct Ad Unit Id.
> Give it 24 hours, it can take time for an ad to become active in your region
> ```

Please try following guidelines [here](https://quickappninja.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002693285-Why-aren-t-my-Admob-ads-showing-).

Check following lines in your code

```
    PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
    mPublisherAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

instead use 
    ((AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView)).loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

Comment: as already said in the post, im using my ad unit ids, and my app id, but i have one question,         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>                                                  
  admob app id and application id are the same right?

Comment: and as far as i know i can use admob without having play store linked.

Comment: Why not confirm by going to your admob account and linking the app. It might be something that google have recently updated and it might work.

Comment: and i have ////// in the "<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
     android:value = "your-application-id-goes-here"/>"    because i dont want to show my app id. but im using it there.

Comment: and how do i link the app?, i dont have the app uploaded to play store because i cant pay the 25 dollars right now.

Comment: and where am i supposed to put the "((AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView)).loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());" code?

Comment: In your onCreate() method. replace R.id.adView with your AdMob view id.

Comment: Make sure you have updated AdMob with your payment details   -- I cant because i need a minimal ammount of money earned.
Make sure that the ads you created in AdMob are banner ads.  -- yup
Check your AdMob dashboard to see the status of your ads, are they active? --nope, none of them are active.
Verify you used the correct Ad Unit Id. --done
Give it 24 hours, it can take time for an ad to become active in your region --some of them already have more than 4 days.

Comment: pd: what is the admob view id? you mean ad id? app id?

Comment: This is the guidelines I quoted from the reference given below. Please check whichever are applicable to your case.

Comment: in you layout file where you use <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView ... the android:id = "@+id/id_you_set_here"

Comment: you can accept the answer if it helps you. thank you.

Comment: okay i found it... it is this:         <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/publisherAdView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: but i still dont know where to place the code you gave me, when i paste it it gives me errors

Comment: You are using PublisherAdView. Please update your question accordingly. My reply was for google adMob banner ads

Comment: I suggest you to simply follow the step by step as they prompt in admobe account while adding application from scratch.

Comment: huh? yes, im trying to put banner ads on my app, and theres banner ads and interstitial ads :/

Comment: and whats the difference?

Comment: Why you are using com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView class instead of com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView??

Comment: because thats the one someone used in the tutorial i saw, and its the only one that worked for me at all, atleast for some time, the other ones always gave me errors, crashesh or just never shown up :(